# Switch-Case using quote (')

Tags: java, char, switch-statement

This is my code, it gives me an error when I wanna check if the case is `'`

```
Case: '.' Case: '?' Case: '!' Case: '''
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the ' with a \

```
Case: '\''
```

Comment: It worked, thanks, now I know how to do this. I'm a noob lol.

Answer (score 3):

```
Case: '\''
```

Escape it with a backslash: `\`